# How to Properly Define Execution Order in NestJS Interceptors with Dependency Injection?

Tags: javascript, nestjs, interceptor

I am working on a NestJS application, where I need to intercept a GET request. The interceptor accepts two parameters; the first one is an array and the second one is a service that is injected. I want to make sure that the `DataConsistencySourceSetter` interceptor (which sets sources for data consistency check) is executed first, and then the `DataConsistencyChecker` interceptor (which checks for data consistency) is executed.

However, defining it in the current way makes the interceptor global and the execution order is not guaranteed. How can I ensure a defined order of execution for these interceptors?

Here is the snippet of my code for the interceptors:

```js
@Injectable()
export class DataConsistencyChecker implements NestInterceptor{
    constructor(private readonly monitoringService: MonitoringService) {};

    async intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler<any>): Promise<Observable<any>> {
        logger.debug("Entered DataConsistencyCheckInterceptor");
        const req = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
        const sources: Sources[] = req.sources;
        const consistencyLevel = req.query._consistency;  // consistencyLevel is a query parameter

        if (consistencyLevel === LatencyLevel.HIGH) {
            const isConsistencyMet = await this.monitoringService.isAlertConditionMet(sources);
            
            if (!isConsistencyMet) {
                throw new ForbiddenException("Data consistency check failed for one or more sources");
            }
        }

        return next.handle();
    }
}

@Injectable()
class DataConsistencySourceSetter implements NestInterceptor {
    constructor(
        private readonly sources: Sources[]
    ) {}

    intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler<any>): Observable<any> {
        logger.debug("Entered DataConsistencySourceSetter");
        const req = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
        req.sources = this.sources;
        return next.handle();
    }
}

export class DataConsistencyInterceptorFactory {
    static setSources(sources: Sources[]): NestInterceptor {
      return new DataConsistencySourceSetter(sources); 
    }
}
```

Here's the relevant part of the controller:

```js
@Controller('payment')
@UseInterceptors(HttpResponseTransferInterceptor)
@UseFilters(HttpExceptionFilter)
export class ApiController {
    constructor(
        private readonly apiService: ApiService,
        private readonly ingestService: IngestService
    ) {}

    @Get()
    @UseInterceptors(DataConsistencyInterceptorFactory.setSources([Sources.LOAN]), DataConsistencyChecker)
    async getState(@Query() requestDto: PaymentStateRequestDto, @Req() req: any) {
        const result = await this.apiService.fetchPaymentStates(requestDto);
        return result.map(r => plainToInstance(PaymentStateResponseDto, r));
    }
}
```

The interceptor is defined and applied on a route inside a controller, but how can I ensure the order of the interceptors?

Thanks in advance!

In my attempt to solve this problem, I tried to define the order of the interceptors by stacking the `@UseInterceptors` decorators as you can see in the controller:

```js
@Get()
@UseInterceptors(DataConsistencyInterceptorFactory.setSources([Sources.LOAN]), DataConsistencyChecker)
async getState(@Query() requestDto: PaymentStateRequestDto, @Req() req: any) {
    const result = await this.apiService.fetchPaymentStates(requestDto);
    return result.map(r => plainToInstance(PaymentStateResponseDto, r));
}
```

I was expecting that NestJS would execute the interceptors in the order they are declared inside the `@UseInterceptors` decorator, meaning that the `DataConsistencyInterceptorFactory.setSources([Sources.LOAN])` would run first, followed by the `DataConsistencyChecker`.

However, I found that the execution order is not consistent with my expectation. The `DataConsistencyChecker` runs before `DataConsistencyInterceptorFactory.setSources([Sources.LOAN])`, causing an inconsistency in the data consistency check because the sources aren't set before the check happens. I am unsure about how to fix this.

Comment: Do you have a reproduction showing that the order is not respected? [That goes against the docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/request-lifecycle#interceptors) and what I've specifically worked out in the past.

Comment: That is the expected order "(DataConsistencyChecker runs before DataConsistencyInterceptorFactory.setSources([Sources.LOAN]))" because the execution is Last in First out according https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/request-lifecycle.

But the global interceptor goes first than locals.